# TF401289: The current user does not have permissions to create tags

Tags: tfs-2015

I have a user who cannot add Tags in TFS encountering error "TF401289: The current user does not have permissions to create tags."

I knew from the very error that there must be something wrong with his access level. Is there anyway I can add a security role with his account that would only allow him to create Tags and without him adding in as Project Administrator? We're using TFS 2015 by the way.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem using Azure DevOps.  The solution was that the people trying to do this had Stakeholder access and needed Basic access (or Visual Studio access).

Comment: I had the same experience. To confirm, my user had the "Create tag definition" permission set to Allow, so we were confused about why their attempts were being denied. This was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The only Tag permission is the Create Tag Definition at the Team Project level that can be added to any user or security group (and Team).

[image]

Comment: I've seen some posts saying that TFSSecurity command is the only way in adding the Create tag definition to the Team Project level. Is this really the only way to add the Create tag definition? And what if I just set the Create tag definition to Allow via UI instead of TFSSecurity to the security group, will it reflect to the access level of my client?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If you give someone Create Tag in the UI they can create a tag. You don't need to use a TfsSecuroty.exe command...

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct MrHinsh. I saw some posts that in order for me to give Create Tag to a user I must use the TFSSecurity.exe command. Otherwise if I only use the UI the create tag role won't take effect.

Comment: I think that you will have to try it ans see

Comment: I've set explicit allow to "create tag definition" but still the error TF401289 comes up.
How's that?
And I don't see what's the purpose to let it do it if that doesn't work?
What's the problem related to?

Comment: For DevOps/VSTS users: This seemed to still be an issue for me in March 2019, but then when I got this error I removed the people who were in the project administrators group (and set that group to allow tag creation), and then noticed that the same people are also in the contributors team, which is not set to allow tag creation. So I removed these people from the contributors team, which leaves them only in the project administrators group, and then they were able to create tags without the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage the **Create tag definition** permission on web portal as @MrHinsh mentioned. But you can only use TFSSecurity command-line tool to **Delete tag definition**, **Enumerate tag definition**, and **Update tag definition**. That's why we say you can manage tagging permissions mostly from the TFSSecurity command-line tool.

> Although the Create tag definition permission appears in the security
>   settings at the team project level, tagging permissions are actually
>   collection-level permissions that are scoped at the team project level
>   when they appear in the user interface. To scope tagging permissions
>   to a single team project when using the TFSSecurity command, you must
>   provide the GUID for the team project as part of the command syntax.
>   Otherwise, your change will apply to the entire collection.

Detailed information, check this article: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#work-item-tags

Comment: My client inherits his **Create tag definition** from "Contributor" and "Project Valid User". Both groups already have "Allow" **Create tag definition** but still he's not able to create new tags. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: @Noel Go to team project admin page > Security > Type the user name in Filter users and groups box, then check the permission of that user whether Create tag definition is Inherited allow.