# Create tags in DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, devops

We have just started using DevOps within our department to keep track of the different initiatives that we run.
I am set up as an administrator of this project but still I cannot create tags in the work items.
I have the following permission under project settings:

[image]

But still I get the error message:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?
I have searched all over internet for solutions and follow all recommendations.

Thanks!

I tried to create a tag in DevOps but it gives me an error message saying that I don't have the permission.

Comment: Did you check [TF401289: The current user does not have permissions to create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363990/tf401289-the-current-user-does-not-have-permissions-to-create-tags) post? It has the same error. Please, add the error message as text, so the error can be copied and be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To view or modify work items, you must have your **View work items in this node** and **Edit work items in this node** permissions set to Allow. By default, the Contributors group has this permission set.
2. To add new tags to add to work items, you must have **Basic** access or higher and have the project-level **Create new tag definition** permissions set to Allow. Users with Stakeholder access for public projects are allowed to add new tags.

   To check access level of your account. Please go to Organization Settings -> Users -> Find your account from the list.
   [image]

   To check project-level Create new tag definition permissions. Please go to Project Settings -> Permissions -> Users -> find your account from the list and click it.
   [image]

See the detailed info from [Add work item tags to categorize and filter lists and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/add-tags-to-work-items?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your comment. When looking at my user under project configuration --> areas --> security then I have both of these set to allow. The only ones which are set to "not set" are "Create child nodes", "Delete this node" and "Edit work item comments in this node". So it still isn't working even though I have the two above set to allow.

Comment: @Nino L, please go to Organization Settings -> Users. Find your account from the user list and check what's the access level of your account. If it's not **Basic** or higher, please contact your organization owner or Project Collection Administrators to change your access level to Basic at least.

Comment: Based on your description "I am set up as an administrator of this project" in the original ticket, you have been the project administrator of this project. The project administrator already has the highest permissions for this project. If you have not made any changes to your permissions, I suspect that this issue may be related to your access level.

Comment: Liu, you are correct, I noticed that yesterday that I only had the Stakeholder access level. So I have requested Basic now which should hopefully solve it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your update. You should be able to create tags after having Basic access level.  If it's helpful for you, it's suggested that you can accept my answer below according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), so that others who have the similar question with you can know this answer more clearly. Thanks!